# Switch tabs using command + number in WebStorm?

Tags: plugins, ide, webstorm

Is there any way to switch tabs using command+number? 
This feature is available in Atom, Code, and many other IDEs,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately WebStorm does not have such functionality.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68324 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

At the same time -- try **GoToTabs plugin** -- it can do that.

You will have to add keyboard shortcuts yourself: to prevent any possible conflicts with already assigned commands, those actions do not have any shortcuts assigned.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018.3, it is now possible to switch tabs using a keyboard shortcut.

The option name in keymap preference is "Other > Tabs > Select Tab #1"